# iOS devices communication with any Wifi-direct enable devices

Tags: ios, p2p, wifi-direct, multipeer-connectivity

Can i communicate iPhone with any wifi-direct enable devices programmatically ?
   I have used "bonjour protocol" for peer-to-pree communication but i am only able to communicate between two iOS devices.

I want to create an iOS App(remote control) for an wifi-direct enable Android TV,Is this possible ?

I have enable wifi-direct in android phone and able to connect my iPhone with this network.So i thing ,if connection is establish then communication should be possible.
can any one please help me so that i can communicate my iPhone App this any wifi-direct enable devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the multipeer connectivity framework for iOS to communicate between iOS devices.  It will select the appropriate wireless protocol to use based on the circumstances. For this reason, and that it's built on bonjour protocol, I don't believe it will work out of the box with Android.

You can try your own custom framework, or you can experiment with something like [Thali](http://thaliproject.org/) which is built on Cordova and is pretty decent from the small amount I've played with it.

Comment: :- I am able to establish connection between "iPhone wifi" with "Android Wifi direct" so i think both of this should be able to for data communication.But i don't know how i can do this

Comment: I'm not saying a "connection" isn't possible, especially using any sort of custom method such as what I shared, and especially since the protocol used is a basic UDP-based one. Specifically, I'm referring to the multipeer connectivity framework for iOS (bonjour) where apple is handling auth/encryption and certs.  But if you disable authentication and encryption (very, very bad idea), I'm sure there are more options since it's simply just UDP at that point.